# Suppose I have some vector, how can I get a vector containing the nth order interaction terms of its elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

This seems like a simple question but I have not been able to figure out how to do it and have no idea how to google it.

Suppose I have some vector $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$$ and I want the vector with say 2nd order interaction terms, which would be $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & ab & ac & bc\end{bmatrix}$$ Is there some quick way I can do this using simple matrix operations (like elementwise multiplication, kronecker product etc.)? To clarify I want some method that allows me to get a vector with quite high order interaction terms, like 5 or 6, and the elements cannot repeat (I'm aware that if repetition were allowed I could just keep using kronecker products).

Comment: Why are you including $abc$ as a 2nd order interaction? Shouldn't it be of 3rd order?

Comment: @AugSB , Sorry, that was a mistake. Up to the nth order would also be helpful though.

Comment: Are these elements $[a \ b \ c]$ also second order interaction terms?

Comment: Would matrix multiplication be considered 'simple'?

Answer (score 4):

Note that product of the original vector $\,\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix}\,$ by its transpose on the left gives you all desired 2nd order terms in square matrix:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & ab & ac \\ ab & b^2 & bc \\ ac & bc & c^2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

One can improve on the expression above by appending original vector with $1$:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ a \\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b & c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b & c\\ a & a^2 & ab & ac \\ b & ab & b^2 & bc \\ c & ac & bc & c^2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

By rearranging and disregarding redundant entries of resulting matrix one can get desired vector

\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & ab & ac & bc\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Can this be generalized to $n$ order terms?

Comment: @AugSB Yes, you can get all the terms up to fourth order if you do the same procedure (take tensor product) of the resulting vector$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & ab & ac & bc\end{bmatrix}$$Keep repeating procedure to get desired order terms.

Comment: In the case where you want second order terms you simply need to delete the upper triangular elements and vectorize. But for 3rd order and above there is no simple pattern for deleting the elements.

Answer (score 2):

When absorbing the answer by Vlad, a generalization to for example $(1+a+b+c)^3$ would lead to a *tensor* eventually: $T_{i,j,k} = r_i r_j r_k$ with $(r_0,r_1,r_2,r_3) = (1,a,b,c)$ and $0 \le i,j,k \le 3$.
But it's easier to do no vector or tensor calculus at all and look at the question as a *combinatorial problem*. Then we have the following (Delphi Pascal) progam and its output. It can be generalized easily to larger vectors (`rij`) and more combinations (nested loops).

```
program suppose;

procedure test;
const
  rij : array[0..3] of char = ('1','a','b','c');
var
  i,j,k : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 3 do
    for j := i to 3 do
      for k := j to 3 do
        Writeln(rij[i],rij[j],rij[k]);
end;

begin
  test;
end.
```

Output:

```
111
11a
11b
11c
1aa
1ab
1ac
1bb
1bc
1cc
aaa
aab
aac
abb
abc
acc
bbb
bbc
bcc
ccc
```

It is noticed that one can also evaluate a product like $(1+a+b+c)^3$ while ignoring the numeric coefficients.